# The Babel Brotherhood - #2

Tags: language

Inspired by @Racso's Babel Brotherhood #1, I've decided to create one as well. Good luck to you all! Also, @Racso, I would love some feedback on my first attempt so I can make sure my future renditions do your puzzles justice!

---

The Babel Brotherhood is composed of people from all around the world.

---

Two members of the Brotherhood, codenames Typhoon and Washington, where enjoying a nice vacation after their previous missions. They were sitting on the beach drinking Mai Tais and trying to figure out what activities they wanted to do the next day. After half an hour, Washington asked Typhoon what time it was; she responded and Washington began scratching her back. He then asked again, *what time is it*?

What did Typhoon say, and why did Washington begin scratching her back?

Comment: Haha, I'm glad you liked the puzzle format enough to make your own puzzles. It seems to me that this one fits with the idea I had in mind. It was possibly on the hard side (at least for me), but it was cool. On an unrelated note, it's Racso, not Rasco ;)

Comment: @Racso Thanks! I did quite enjoy the first one, and I plan to make another; perhaps later tonight or tomorrow. Apologies for the misspell, I've corrected lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps Typhoon said

> *ichi*, the Japanese for "one"

and Washington

> thought she had said "itchy".

But

> I'm not sure whether you can just say "one" when it's one o'clock,

so another possibility is that Typhoon

> said something like "hachi-ji", meaning "eight o'clock"

and Washington

> thought she had said "back itchy". Though that seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: You are correct that the language typically follows a more formal flow when speaking; however, just like with any language, you can "*short hand*" things. +1